# JQuery function on form submit

Tags: jquery

I have this JQuery function:

```
function CheckRequired() {
    alert("test");

    var ret = true;

    $(".required").each( function() {
        var check = $(this).val();

        if(check == '') {
            //alert($(this).attr("id"));
            event.preventDefault();
            ret = false;
        }
    });

    if(!ret) {
        alert("One or more fields cannot be blank");
        return false;
    }
}
```

which checks for all input fields with a class of `required`

i have many forms on on my site and i do not call this function on every form.

is there a way i can do this on every form submit without adding any extra code to each form?

Answer (score 2):

Use event delegation with jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', CheckRequired);
```

Also, if you wish to use `CheckRequired` instead of an anonymous function, be sure to modify its decleration to accept the `event` parameter

```
function CheckRequired(event) {...}
```

Comment: That's just event binding, not delegation.

Comment: i just added this code and at the top of the `CheckRequired` function i added `alert("test")` - then when i submit a form its not showing

Comment: Still need to pass `event` to support FF and btw, should check inside `CheckRequired()` only for inputs inside specific FORM

Comment: @charlie So replicate your issue online (e.g on jsFiddle) so we can see what's going wrong

Comment: @A.Wolff, silly question, but how would we pass the event in this case? CheckRequired, event... ?

Comment: @charlie, try replacing CheckRequired with an anonymous function and see if it works. anonymous meaning function(e){...your code above...}

Comment: @AmmarCSE Setting function handler as it: `function CheckRequired(event) {...}` FF using a different event model, `window.event` is undefined

Comment: i have just tried this - http://jsfiddle.net/cry58kux/1/ - its working okay in the fiddle but in my code its still submitting the form